# Generating object file to separate directory using g++ compiler - C++

Tags: c++, g++

I use the following code to compile a cpp file to object file.

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

Above code generates the .o fles in same directory where main.cpp resides.

1. Suppose I have a folder named obj and need to generate the object files there, how could I write it?
2. How can I see the compiler switches supported by g++ and it's usages?

Any help would be great

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Suppose I have a folder named obj and need to generate the object files there, how do I write?

Use:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -o obj/main.o
```

> How can I see the compiler switches supported by g++ and it's usages?

If you are on a *nix system use:

```
man g++
```

or use `info g++`

Comment: not to be a jerk but you kind of just edited your question and added more detail about man pages that I already had in my original question.

Comment: One more thing, if you note, I mentioned the system man as opposed to the online collection and info. These were missing. I did see your edit after making the edit and did not re-edit since I think our answers _combined_ more or less a completely says whatever there is to say. But you are right to believe otherwise.

Comment: sounds like some kind of collaborative answer with point sharing would be helpful in this kinda situation, eh?

Answer (score 10):

If you type

```
$man g++
```

Here's the [man page online](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++) You'll probably get gobs of good information there. You can also try

```
$g++ --help
```

To your question. If you used the -o switch, you can specify the output file to use. So you could probably do something like

```
$g++ -c main.cpp -o obj/main.obj
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer to question 2: More information about the compiler switches can be found in the [online manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary).